# Configuration of Azure for Storage and Hadoop Clustered Processing

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

Hope someone can offer any advice. At the moment I have been asked to scope out a possible infrastructure for a new Azure Platform. We are also going to be using HDFS / Hadoop for our ETL and Storage.

Can anyone offer any advice on the following :

Set up a Storage Optimised Server (eg, L4, 4 Core, 32gb Ram, 678 GB Storage) to hold our raw data, reference tables and final cleansed data within HDFS.  This server could be running 24/7 to feed our analytics platforms.

Then, to utilise the power of Hadoop, could we spin up a set of Processing servers (eg, once a week) to read from the Storage Server, process and write back to the storage server and then shutdown until the next load & process task.

Would really appreciate anyone's thoughts advice on this or any possible configurations we could think of?

Many thanks

Fiorano

Answer (score 0):

Whether your Hadoop cluster is on-premises or in the cloud, it contains two main resources: compute resources to process jobs, and storage resources to hold data.  In an on-premises cluster, the storage and compute resources are combined into the same hardware tying them together.  With HDInsight the storage is wholly separated from the compute resource.  This is a very important distinction of HDInsight.  It means that I can completely turn off the compute portion of the cluster and the data will remain accessible.

**Note:** To analyze data in HDInsight cluster, you can store the data either in [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage), [Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fhdinsight%2Fhadoop%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json), or both.

For more details, refer "[Azure HDInsight Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/hdinsight/)".